# Fork : concurrency or parallelism

Tags: c, fork

I was recently doing some experiments with the `fork` function and I was concerned by a "simple" (short) question:

- Does `fork` uses concurrency or parallelism (if more than one core) mechanisms?
- Or, is it the OS which makes the best choice?

Thanks for your answer.

*nb: Damn I fork bombed myself again!*

### Edit:

1. Concurrency: Each operation run on one core. Interrupts are received in order to switch from one process to another (Sequential computation).
2. Parallelism: Each operation run on two cores (or more).

Comment: Explain the difference between "concurrency" and "parallelism".

Comment: Assuming you are using "concurrency" to refer to two processes timeslicing on a single core, and "parallelism" to refer to them running on different cores ......   it depends.   The OS will make some choice, based on memory resources, loading, how many other programs and threads are running, and a whole bunch of factors.  But this can vary between operating system and even be affected by administrative settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fork()` duplicates the current process, creating another independent process. End of story.

How the kernel chooses to schedule these processes is a different, very broad question. In general the kernel will try to use all available resources (cores) to run as many tasks as possible. When there are more runnable tasks than cores, it has to start making decisions about who gets to run, and for how long.

Answer (score 2):

The fork function creates a separate *process*. It is up to the operating system how it handles different processes.

Of course, if only once core is available, the OS has no other choice but running all processes *interleaved*.

If more cores are available, every sane OS will distribute the processes to the different cores, so every core runs at least one process.
However, even then, more processes can be active than there are cores. So even then, it is up to the OS to decide which processes can be run parallel (by distributing to cores) and which have to be run interleaved (on a single core).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, [fork()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) is a system call (aka. system service) which creates a new process from the current process (read the return code to see who you are, the parent or the child).

In the UNIX work, processes shares the CPU computing time. This works like that :

1. a process is running
2. the clock generates an interrupt, calling the kernel and pausing the process
3. the kernel takes the list of available processes, and decide to resume one (this is called scheduling)
4. go to point 1)

When there is multiples processor cores, kernels are able to dispatch processes on them.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can do something. Write a complex program say, O(n^3), so that it takes a good amount of time to compute. fork() four times (if you have quad-core). Now open any graphical CPU monitor. Anything cool?